# AS3 Event architecture

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having difficulty with the last piece in the puzzle on AS3 events.

I understand target classes inherit from EventDispatch or implement IEventDispatch and can register (amongst other methods) event listeners.

However what do the target classes register with? If an Event happens, how does AS3 know to pass the Event to the target classes?

Regards,
shwell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For objects in the display list, the following excerpt from Adobe is the answer "When Adobe® Flash® Player dispatches an Event object, that Event object makes a roundtrip journey from the root of the display list to the target node, checking each node for registered listeners.".

For non display objects, AS3 run time maintains a dictionary of all AS3 events containing bound variables. The bound variables are a reference to the event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article about event phases and it will make more sense:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_02.html

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: Well, now **I** don't get some things. How does Flash player know which object should be a target of an event, for example, on a mouse click event? What exact methods does it use to determine the actual target? Same for moving, does it check for an object being obscured by other objects, or not? It can be done via filtering `getObjectsUnderPoint()` for the topmost `IEventDispatcher` and designating that one as target, but it's a wild guess mostly.

Comment: Hello Romi, This line from your link explains what happens for display objects, and mostly answers my question. But what about non display objects? - "When Adobe® Flash® Player dispatches an Event object, that Event object makes a roundtrip journey from the root of the display list to the target node, checking each node for registered listeners." Although I can imagine a similar 'round trip' for non display objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at how starling event works

[starling even dispatcher](https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/starling/events/EventDispatcher.as)

When a displayObject bubbles an event,  it will check if the parent of the displayObject exist and add the parent to bubbleList if exist util the ancestor of displayObject is null.

The following code is in starling eventDispatcher

```
var element:DisplayObject = this as DisplayObject;
var chain:Vector.<EventDispatcher> = new <EventDispatcher>[element];

while ((element = element.parent) != null)
    chain[int(length++)] = element;
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, Starling created a completely different Event architecture/pattern for their framework because the Flash architecture is admittedly heavy, especially when it comes to Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3, `EventDispatcher` is an implementation of the observer design pattern. This class implement the `addEventLister`, `removeEventListener`, `dispatchEvent' and`hasEventListener` methods. Internally, it also maintains a dictionary or similar data structure that contains the events which are currently being listened for, and a list of methods which have to be called when the event is dispatched. Something like this -

```
{"event1": [method7, method5, method3], "event2": [method3, method2], "event3": [method1]};
```

When `addEventListener` is called on an object, it creates a new key for the event in question and adds the method reference to its associated value list.

When `dispatchEvent` is called on the class, it fetches all the methods associated with the event and calls the methods attached with it. Each method is called with an instance of the `Event` class or its subclasses.

Removing an event listener obviously does the opposite of what adding does.

Comment: Hello Pranav, if the dictionary is external to the targets, it seems a reference to the target must also be stored? Is this right?

Comment: By target I assume you mean the class which is dispatching the event. In this case, no, the dictionary is not external. The class inherits from EventDispatcher, so the dictionary becomes internal to the class itself.

Comment: I think I get it now, is the event passed to all EventDispatch classes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing of `addEventListener()` mechanics. This thing has a global side effect on event engine, registering a callback function along with caller `this` value to provide correct context of a fired event, with possible update of `event.localX` and `event.localY` properties by calling `globalToLocal()` either statically or dynamically, as the event bubbles up and down.

If you are, like me, confused about how does Flash player determine the target of an event - there is an internal "focus" pointer that determines which component of the SWF has keyboard focus, and that one is used to target keyboard events. For mouse events, most likely Flash engine calls `getObjectsUnderPoint()` to query for topmost `IEventDispatcher` compatible objects (not all of the DisplayObjects can process events), and that one is sent a mouse event, with the previous event's target to receive a say `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` or `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` if the target has been changed. For other events, most likely the entire display list can react.